# Keep the drawings when scrolling on TableLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls

In the TableLayoutPanel, one of the rows at once is highlighted with a red rectangle around through the function:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(MyTableLayoutPanel.CreateGraphics, RowRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
```

When I scroll the Panel, the rectangle disappear.

How can I keep it after scrolling without having to redraw it on the TLP.Paint event?

I've already tried:

```
DrawRectangle()
MyTableLayoutPanel.Invalidate() 'And also Invalidate(True)
```

But it doesn't work; even worst, with Invalidate, it clears the rectangle before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateGraphics` is a very temporary drawing.  You should use the Graphic object from that paint event:

```
Private Sub MyTableLayoutPanel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
                                     Handles MyTableLayoutPanel.Paint

  ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rowRectangle, Color.Red, _
                          ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
```

Comment: @StefanoObjektum ...and the reason is?